# Reading map data from local text file using Javascript and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dictionary, text-files

I'm trying to make a game in HTML5 and i'm trying to load a map level into the game from a text file through JavaScript. I've looked at a few questions already but for some reason the code isn't working. Could someone have a look and tell me if there's anything glaringly obvious?

```
$.get('js/mapFile.txt',function(data){
    alert();
    var perLine=data.split('\n');
    var myVars=[];
    for(i=0;i<perLine.length;i++)
    {
    var line=perLine[i].split(',');
    myVars[i]={
        'time':line[0],
        'event':line[1],
        'color':line[2],
        'type':line[3]
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "" + myVars[0].time + "Jimmy";
});
```

this is just demo code btw, I'm gonna adapt it when I get the principal working

Comment: What do you mean by local? Is this running from a web server or via file:///?

Comment: what error do you get? What the output of your js console?

Comment: Sorry this is my first time using StackOverflow so my code is all scrunched together

Comment: Local as in, it's all running from the same directory and not over the internet, and I don't have a console that works. I'm not really a scripting programmer so some of this is quite new and difficult

Comment: You won't get far with JavaScript using the local filesystem - it has to be via http. Install a web server on your local machine, your JS will work as if it was on the internet.

Comment: How do I install a web server then?